# Is there a way to connect to 4d database from oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, 4d-database

In our work environment We have old 4D database system. we want to migrate the data to oracle, before that i would like to connect the 4d database tables and other objects from oracle database.

This is totally new to me. I would appreciate if anyone can share there knowledge on this.

Comment: Is the 4D database compiled or interpreted? That is, can you access the code and settings or only use the application?

Comment: Good question @Joshua - Since this site is about programming i would hope they have the source code and not just the compiled application. Also, which version of 4D?

Comment: A developer installed this db on his work system.The version is 13.6. I am not sure whether its compiled or interpreted. He said he can run it just from his system or if he want he can connect to it from other machines.

Answer (score 0):

## From Oracle:

#### ODBC

You could use ODBC to connect *from* Oracle to 4D Server.

You would need to install the [4D ODBC Driver](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15R3/4D/15-R3/4D-ODBC-Driver.100-2814232.en.html) appropriate to your environment on the Oracle machine. Remember to match the version of ODBC Driver to the version of 4D and the architecture of the ODBC Driver with the architecture of the ODBC Client (Oracle in this case).

For example, if your 4D Server is running v15.2 and Oracle is running in 64 bit mode, you would then want to use the [4D v15.2 ODBC Driver 64 bit](http://download.4d.com/Products/Current/4D_v15_2/Installers/ODBC/Windows/4D_ODBC_Driver_v15_2_Windows_64-bit.exe)

On the other hand if 4D Server is running 14.5 and Oracle is running in 32 bit mode, you would want to install the [4D v14.5 ODBC Driver 32 bit](http://download.4d.com/Products/Current/4D_v14_5/Installers/ODBC/Windows/4D_ODBC_Driver_v14_5_Windows_32-bit.exe)

The ODBC Drivers can be downloaded from http://4d.com/downloads/products.html

Here are some general instructions for [connecting to an ODBC server from Oracle](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/134578/88457)

#### Native SQL Protocol

The 4D SQL Protocol is documented at [Github - 4D/SQLlib_4D](https://github.com/4D/SQLlib_4D) and also on [sources.4d.com](http://sources.4d.com/trac/4d_pdo4d/raw-attachment/wiki/WikiStart/SQL%20networking%20protocol.doc) so theoretically you could write a connector of some sort.

---

## From 4D:

#### ODBC

You could use ODBC to connect from 4D Server to Oracle.

You would need to install the appropriate [Oracle ODBC Driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-098155.html) on the 4D Server machine and then connect using [SQL LOGIN](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15R3/4D/15-R3/SQL-LOGIN.301-2695340.en.html)

#### 4D for OCI

You could use the plugin [4D for OCI](http://www.4d.com/products/4dv15/4dforoci.html) which has [documentation here](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15R3/4D/15-R3/4D-for-OCI.100-2812834.en.html)

Comment: Thank you. I have installed the 4d ODBC driver and in ODBC data source administrator i configured the 4d datasource. But i am not sure about the next steps. how i can use this in oracle database to connect to 4D?

Comment: Is it not possible to connect to an external ODBC database from Oracle like you can from MS SQL Server? If that is not possible in Oracle then you would have to connect the other way, to Oracle from 4D.

Comment: @TimPenner Once you have the ODBC side set up, then the procedures should be the same as: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111985/step-by-step-establish-a-connection-between-sql-server-2014-and-oracle-12c/134578#134578 If you run into issues with certain commands over the DB link, then look into dbms_hs_passthrough: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_hspass.htm

Comment: Thanks @KrisJohnston that seems to be the missing piece!